# Get compile error on Lineage 16.0 when brunch bacon

Tags: android-source, lineageos

I am building customer ROM for my OnePluse 1 phone based on lineage 16.0. After making some changes and brunch bacon, i got below error:

```
ju@suz-ubt-01l:~/android/lineage$ brunch bacon

...
...
...

build/target/product/core.mk was modified, regenerating...

[625/1039] including system/sepolicy/Android.mk ...

system/sepolicy/Android.mk:88: warning: Be careful when using the SELINUX_IGNORE_NEVERALLOWS flag. It does not work in user builds and using it will not stop you from failing CTS.

[1039/1039] including vendor/qcom/opensource/dataservices/Android.mk ...
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `/home/ju/android/lineage/out/target/product/bacon/system/vendor/lib/hw/android.hardware.nfc@1.0-impl.so'

build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/home/ju/android/lineage/out/target/product/bacon/system/vendor/lib/hw/android.hardware.nfc@1.0-impl.so'

[ 86% 94/109] Building Kernel Config

make: Entering directory '/home/ju/android/lineage/kernel/oppo/msm8974'
  GEN     /home/ju/android/lineage/out/target/product/bacon/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/Makefile
#
# configuration written to .config
#

make: Leaving directory '/home/ju/android/lineage/kernel/oppo/msm8974'

make: Entering directory '/home/ju/android/lineage/kernel/oppo/msm8974'

  GEN     /home/ju/android/lineage/out/target/product/bacon/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/Makefile
scripts/kconfig/conf --savedefconfig=defconfig Kconfig

make: Leaving directory '/home/ju/android/lineage/kernel/oppo/msm8974'

[ 87% 95/109] Building Kernel

FAILED: TARGET_KERNEL_BINARIES 

/bin/bash -c "(make -j2  -j\$(nproc) CFLAGS_MODULE=\"-fno-pic\" -C kernel/oppo/msm8974 O=/home/ju/android/lineage/out/target/product/bacon/obj/KERNEL_OBJ ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=\"/usr/bin/ccache arm-linux-androidkernel-\"   zImage ) && (if grep -q '^CONFIG_OF=y' /home/ju/android/lineage/out/target/product/bacon/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/.config; then           echo \"Building DTBs\";make -j2  -j\$(nproc) CFLAGS_MODULE=\"-fno-pic\" -C kernel/oppo/msm8974 O=/home/ju/android/lineage/out/target/product/bacon/obj/KERNEL_OBJ ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=\"/usr/bin/ccache arm-linux-androidkernel-\"   dtbs;       fi ) && (if grep -q '=m' /home/ju/android/lineage/out/target/product/bacon/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/.config; then             echo \"Building Kernel Modules\";            make -j2  -j\$(nproc) CFLAGS_MODULE=\"-fno-pic\" -C kernel/oppo/msm8974 O=/home/ju/android/lineage/out/target/product/bacon/obj/KERNEL_OBJ ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=\"/usr/bin/ccache arm-linux-androidkernel-\"   modules;      fi )"
make: Entering directory '/home/ju/android/lineage/kernel/oppo/msm8974'
  File "/home/ju/android/lineage/kernel/oppo/msm8974/scripts/gcc-wrapper.py", line 59
    print "error, forbidden warning:", m.group(2)
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  GEN     /home/ju/android/lineage/out/target/product/bacon/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/Makefile
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
  File "/home/ju/android/lineage/kernel/oppo/msm8974/scripts/gcc-wrapper.py", line 59
    print "error, forbidden warning:", m.group(2)
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  GEN     /home/ju/android/lineage/out/target/product/bacon/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/Makefile
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
  File "/home/ju/android/lineage/kernel/oppo/msm8974/scripts/gcc-wrapper.py", line 59
    print "error, forbidden warning:", m.group(2)
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
/home/ju/android/lineage/kernel/oppo/msm8974/scripts/Makefile.build:307: recipe for target 'scripts/mod/empty.o' failed
make[3]: *** [scripts/mod/empty.o] Error 1
/home/ju/android/lineage/kernel/oppo/msm8974/scripts/Makefile.build:443: recipe for target 'scripts/mod' failed
make[2]: *** [scripts/mod] Error 2
/home/ju/android/lineage/kernel/oppo/msm8974/Makefile:510: recipe for target 'scripts' failed
make[1]: *** [scripts] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:130: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/ju/android/lineage/kernel/oppo/msm8974'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
10:45:43 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (01:13 (mm:ss)) ####
```

My environment info as below:

PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL

PLATFORM_VERSION=9

LINEAGE_VERSION=16.0-20200110-UNOFFICIAL-bacon

TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_bacon

TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug

TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release

TARGET_ARCH=arm

TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon

TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=krait

HOST_ARCH=x86_64

HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86

HOST_OS=linux

HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.0.0-37-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-18.04.3-LTS

HOST_CROSS_OS=windows

HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86

HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64

HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release

BUILD_ID=PQ3A.190801.002

OUT_DIR=/home/ju/android/lineage/out

PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES= hardware/qcom/audio-caf/msm8974 hardware/qcom/display-caf/msm8974
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8974

My python version is "Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda, Inc."
Andy help should be appreciated, Thank you very much.

Comment: does your system default to python 3? just go to the python file which is causing the error and change the shebang to a python2 shebang.

Comment: After long struggle, i decide to clean and re-sync the source code. Now i get the build result lineage-16.0-20200129-UNOFFICIAL-bacon.zip file successfully. @Daniel, i think you are right. I used Python 2.7.17 in my final build. As newcomer, build android OS is hard work for me, thanks Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Create Conda environment with python version 2.7